# Criar DataTable Dinamicamente

Tags: c#, ado.net, datatable

Necessito de Criar um `DataTable` Dinâmico;

do género:

```
List<p> =...
List<l>=....

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
foreach (Prod pr in p)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(prod.Nome.Trim());
    for (int i = 0; i < l.Count; i++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(GetDados(pr,l[i]),GetDados(pr,l[i])...);
    }
}
```

Meu problema está dentro do `for`, como posso inserir linhas na datable, quando essas linhas não são definidas, sendo o número de colunas dinâmico?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode criar um DataTAble dinamicamente, mas deve fazer por partes. Primeiro definir as colunas e depois inserir linhas de acordo com as colunas, por exemplo:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

// defina as colunas da DataTable
foreach (Prod pr in p)
    dt.Columns.Add(pr.Nome.Trim());

// insira linhas
for (int i = 0; i < l.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    foreach (Prod pr in p)  
    {
        row[pr.Nome.Trim()] = GetDados(pr,l[i]);
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Obs: Seu código não está 100%, mas acredito que o caminho é por ai